# Calculate birthdate from year, month and days

Tags: javascript, date, calculator

I'm working on a calculator that needs to calculate the date of birth from 3 inputs: the age in years, months and days:

```js
    const arrDatas = [];
    const elmDataNasc = document.querySelector('#dataNasc');

    function setDataAnos (e) { // store at position 0 of arrDates the years

        arrDatas[0] = e;
        setDataNasc();

    }

    function setDataMeses (e) { // store in position 1 of arrDatas the months

        arrDatas[1] = e;
        setDataNasc();

    }

    function setDataDias (e) { // store in position 2 of arrDatas the days

        arrDatas[2] = e;
        setDataNasc();

    }

    function setDataNasc () {

        let anosDias = arrDatas[0] * 365; // convert years to days
        let mesesDias = arrDatas[1] * 30.417; // convert months to days (30,417 is the average of days per month)
        let diasDias = arrDatas[2]; // Days

        let totalDias = anosDias + mesesDias + diasDias; // add the total number of days and assign it to a variable

        let dataData = new Date(); // current date

        dataData.setDate( dataData.getDate() - totalDias); // subtract total days from the current date

        let data = dataData.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", { year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit",}); // format to DD/MM/YYYY

        elmDataNasc.value = data; // assign date to birthdate input
        
    }
```

```html
<form>
            <p>Enter data to calculate date of birth:</p>

            <label for="years">Years</label>
            <input onchange="setDataAnos(this.value)" type="number" name="years" min="0" max="31">

            <label for="months">Months</label>
            <input onchange="setDataMeses(this.value)" type="number" name="months" min="0" max="11">

            <label for="days">Days</label>
            <input onchange="setDataDias(this.value)" type="number" name="days" min="0" max="31">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="dateBirth">Date of birth:</label>
            <input id="dataNasc" type="text" name="dataNasc" value="" disabled>
        </form>
```

This script only allows you to calculate an approximate date, as it does not take into account the exact number of days in each month or leap years.
I would like her to calculate the exact date of birth but I have no idea how to do that, I've racked my brains and searched the internet but nothing.
Any light?

Comment: I doubt it would be possible because you can never know how many months had 31 days just from a number

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thanks for your awswer! Do you have any suggestions for another approach to arriving at an exact date?

Comment: A person is a certain number of days, months and years old relative to a particular date. If you know that date or you assume it to be the date today then the exact number of months with 31, 30, 28 and 29 days is a known fact which can be found by referring to a calendar. Javascript's date functions are will take this information in to consideration and therefore can give you the precise birthday of a person given the days, months and years they have been alive today (or on any other date).

Comment: @KonradLinkowski You don't have one "number" you have 2. One is the days, months and years. The other is the date which they apply to which is normally the date today. Given that we have calendars which document every date it is absolutely possible to determine what the date of birth was given the number days, months & years from any given date. My answer does it exactly the accepted answer does it approximately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the values for year, month and day in one go so the Date object does the maths for you, including leap years and different length months.

Consider someone born on 28 Feb 1957. On 31 Jan 2020 (datum) they are 62 years, 11 months and 3 days old. If you subtract that from the datum, you should get the correct birthday.

Similarly, someone born on 29 Mar 1957 is 62 years and 11 months old on 29 Feb 2020.

Someone born on 31 Mar 1957 is 62 years, 10 months and 29 days old on 29 Feb 2020.

E.g.

```js
function calcBirthday(y=0, m=0, d=0, datum = new Date()) {
  return new Date(
    datum.getFullYear() - y, 
    datum.getMonth() - m,
    datum.getDate() - d);
}

// Someone who is 62 years, 11 months and 3 days old on 31 Jan 2020
// was born on 28 Feb 1957
console.log(calcBirthday(62, 11, 3, new Date(2020,0,31))
            .toDateString());

// Someone who is 62 years, 11 months old on 29 Feb 2020
// was born on 29 Mar 1957
console.log(calcBirthday(62, 11, 0, new Date(2020,1,29))
            .toDateString());

// Someone who is 62 years, 10 months, 29 days old on 29 Feb 2020
// was born on 31 Mar 1957
console.log(calcBirthday(62, 10, 29, new Date(2020,1,29))
            .toDateString());

// Someone who is 1 year, 1 month and 1 day old today was
// was born on…
console.log(calcBirthday(1, 1, 1).toDateString());

// Someone who is 1 year old on 29 Feb 2020 was
// was born on…
console.log(calcBirthday(1, 0, 0, new Date(2020,1,29))
            .toDateString());
```

The caveat is that valid values for age in years, months and days must be entered, otherwise there are no guarantees as to the result. Also 29 Feb has some anomalies.

Comment: Thank you! I'm marking your answer as correct because it worked with all the dates I've tested, although I have to heavily adapt it for my needs hahaha

Comment: @RobG I tried your three scenarios in my answer (which I have modified to accept any date as the ending date not just today's date) and all three gave the correct date of birth. In view of that I am giving your answer an up vote!

Comment: Be aware, this solution gives an unexpected answer for someone 1 month old on the 31st of July: `calcBirthday(0,1,0,new Date(2022,6,31));`

Comment: @BenjaminPenney—it is impossible to be exactly 1 month old on 31 July as there is no 31 June (assuming the Gregorian calendar). On 31 July a person born on 30 June is one month and one day old, and a person born the following day on 1 July is 31 days old. Though I guess a better answer would detect such errors and either throw an error or return *undefined*.

Comment: I'm confused. You claimed this was an error in my solution.

Comment: @BenjaminPenney and RobG I think that if someone was only a month old most people would pick up on the anomaly that "it is impossible to be exactly 1 month old on 31 July...". However, that basic category of imprecision (or error) is exactly what we do all the time when considering how many years, months and days old somebody is. We talk in whole months regardless of how many days they contain.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to "*calculate the date of birth from 3 inputs: the age in years, months and days*". I think the only sensible way someone would arrive at those 3 parameters (years, months and days) would be to follow these 3 steps:

- Get the number of *full, calendar* years there have been since year of birth until the current year.
- Get the number of *full, calendar* months there have been since month of birth until the current month.
- Get the number of (all *full* except for 1 day which would be either the day they were born on *or* the end date) days there have been since day of birth until current day.

I used the word calendar to stress that I do *not* mean 365 days when I say year or any particular number of days for months. A given number of years, months and days represents a different total number of days depending on which actual calendar days they span.

The requirement is to reverse the 3 steps shown above so that you arrive back at the date you originally started on. The 3 steps can be done in any order.

- Subtract the number of days from the date now to give a new date.
- Subtract the number of months from that date to give a new date.
- Subtract the number of years from that date to give the date you want.

This code does that and it does seem to give correct results from the tests I have done.

```js
const days = 22;
const months = 4;
const years = 63;

let d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - days);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - months);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - years);
console.log(d);
```

Here is a version where you can enter days, months and years ago from today and see the date that is was then:

```js
const days = document.querySelector('#days');
const months = document.querySelector('#months');
const years = document.querySelector('#years');
const until = document.querySelector('#until');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const p = document.querySelector('p')

function padTo2Digits(num) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

function formatDate(date = new Date()) {
  return [
    date.getFullYear(),
    padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1),
    padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),
  ].join('-');
}

until.value = formatDate();

btn.addEventListener('click',
  function(){
    const d = parseInt(days.value);
    const m = parseInt(months.value);
    const y = parseInt(years.value);
    
    const dt = new Date(until.value);
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - d);
    dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - m);
    dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() - y);

    p.innerHTML = `${d} days, ${m} months and ${y} years before ${until.value} the date was ${dt.toLocaleDateString()}`;
  }
);
```

```html
    <form>
      <input id='days' type='number' size='5'>
      <label for='days'>days</label>
      <br>
      <input id='months' type='number' size='5'>
      <label for='months'>months</label>
      <br>
      <input id='years' type='number' size='5'>
      <label for='years'>years</label>
      <br>
      <label for='until'>until</label>
      <input id='until' type='date' size='5'>
      <br>
      <button type='button'>Submit</button>
      </form>
      
      <p></p>
```

Two people who died on different days but both lived for the same number of years, months and days may have lived for a different total number of days. This is because their lives may have spanned different numbers of Feb 29ths and months ending on the 30th or 31st.

*Years, months and days* is not a good measure of time as the length of time they denote depends on the date they are relative to and requires a complex calculation to express in a better unit of time such as just *days*.

You are probably better to stick with the unperturbed ground-state hyperfine transition frequency of the caesium 133 atom.

Comment: This code subtracts the days first. When performing mental arithmetic to calculate years, months and days, people add/subtract the years first. This is the reason for your perception that my code is 'off by one'. Consider: ```const days = 22;
const months = 4;
const years = 63;

let d = new Date(Date.now());
console.log(d);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - years);
console.log(d);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - months);
console.log(d);
d.setDate(d.getDate() - days);
console.log(d);``` I provided a naive approach because I assumed the OP wanted to do something with `totalDias`.

Comment: Also, this problem is common on the Internet: https://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html?today=06%2F30%2F2020&ageat=11%2F15%2F2022&x=56&y=25 v/s https://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html?today=07%2F01%2F2020&ageat=11%2F15%2F2022&x=58&y=15

Comment: @BenjaminPenney I like your code because you do the thinking. It does get my birthday out by one day. When I work out the days, month and years I have been alive it agrees with the result from https://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html. When I put those days, months and years into your code I am told I was born the day before I was born. My code gets it right. I was born 22 days, 4 months and 63 years ago from today 2022-11-15.

Comment: @BenjaminPenney Today (2022-11-15): Input [0, 0, 22] output is 2022-10-24 which is correct. Input [2, 0, 22] output is 2020-10-23 which can not be consistent with the first result as it should be the same month and year (10-24) as the first result but with the year reduced by 2. It should be 2020-10-24

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` will produce an identical result to `new Date()`.

Comment: @user3425506 I used your script to calculate the date of birth of a person aged 9 years, 4 months and 21 days and it returned the date of 25/06/2013, but the exact date of birth of this person is 24/06/2013, you can check this please?

Comment: @JoãoPauloSaragossa The way I calculate the years, months and days from a given birth date to today gives me 9 years, 4 months and 22 days from 24/06/2013. That agrees with plugging 24/06/2013 into https://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html. I have edited my answer to show how I think a person would normally do the calculation to get years, months, days from their birthday to todays date.

Comment: @user3425506 My post above with two links shows how calculator.net is unreliable.

Comment: @BenjaminPenney It seems that we need to agree on the (possibly) arbitrary method of calculating how many years, months and days old someone is given a birth date and end date. If we agreed on that we would then need to agree whether any method, in all cases, reverses that to give the same birth date date given the years, months and days and end date. At the moment I do not think we are agreed on the first thing. That is how to work out years, months and days given a birth date and end date. Do you agree with the method in my answer (the first list of 3 items)?

Comment: Frankly, I think yours is the only solution here giving wrong answers. Consider this: `const days = 2;
const months = 1;
const years = 0;

let d = new Date(2022,3,1);
d.setDate(d.getDate() - days);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - months);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - years);
console.log(d);` It's the 1st of April and you're 1 month and 2 days old. Your method gives the 2nd of March. Mine and RobG's both give 27th of February. My two links above are for two dates one day apart that give ages two days apart, so please don't trust that calculator.net site!

Comment: Furthermore, if you reverse the order of your operations, you'll arrive at the same answer my method and RobG's method do. I think RobG's comments on my solution may have been intended for you. My method doesn't compute things one-at-a-time, it simply converts all units to days and does one subtraction. The answers with both my and RobG's method line up, however, he's dug his heels in and I now have no idea what supposed problem he's talking about...

Comment: This is the correct order if you want to do the operations one at a time: `const days = 2; const months = 1; const years = 0;  let d = new Date(2022,3,1); console.log(d); d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - years); d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - months); d.setDate(d.getDate() - days); console.log(d);` Also, I hope you don't think I'm rude. I don't mind if we disagree on what answers are right. My checks are all done with mental counting. I just wanted to provide you with a concrete example that disagrees with what most people would consider "right".

Answer (score -1):

Here's a naive approach you should be able to adapt:

```js
let arrDatas = [39, 4, 19];

const isLeapYear = year => (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0;
const daysInYear = year => 365 + (isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0);
const daysInMonth = (year, month) => [31, 28 + (isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];

let when = new Date();
let year = when.getFullYear();
let month = when.getMonth();
let day = when.getDate();

let totalDias = 0;

if(month < 2)
    year--;
for(let i = 0; i < arrDatas[0]; i++)
{
    totalDias += daysInYear(year);
    year--;
}
month--;
for(let i = 0; i < arrDatas[1]; i++)
{
    totalDias += daysInMonth(year, month);
    month--;
}
totalDias += arrDatas[2];

let dataData = new Date();
dataData.setDate(dataData.getDate() - totalDias);

console.log("You were born on", dataData);
```

You can sub in your own values instead of the dummy `arrDatas` in the code above.

This doesn't take into account things like timezone changes and leap seconds.

Also, you will want to validate your input. Think about someone entering 20 years, 3 months and 5383 days.

Addendum:

Here's a variant that works as RobG suggested:

```
let arrDatas = [39, 4, 19];

const isLeapYear = year => (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0;
const daysInYear = year => 365 + (isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0);
const daysInMonth = (year, month) => [31, 28 + (isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];

let when = new Date();
let year = when.getFullYear();
let month = when.getMonth();
let day = when.getDate();

let totalDias = 0;

if(month < 2)
    year--;
for(let i = 0; i < arrDatas[0]; i++)
{
    totalDias += daysInYear(year);
    year--;
}
if(day <= daysInMonth(year, month - 1))
    month--;
for(let i = 0; i < arrDatas[1]; i++)
{
    totalDias += daysInMonth(year, month);
    month--;
}
totalDias += arrDatas[2];

let dataData = new Date();
dataData.setDate(dataData.getDate() - totalDias);

console.log("You were born on", dataData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! About the validation, note that the input of number type has a ´min ´and ´max ´properties, in the case of days I limited it to a maximum of 31.

Comment: I tried this code with my birthday and it was one day out. The code in my answer is exact and shorter!

Comment: This approach doesn't work because subtracting 1 year from 29 February returns 1 March, so a month is skipped. Also, subtracting a month from the 31st of a month may return the 1st of the same month (e.g. 31 July returns 1 July because there is no 31 June) so a few months may or may not be skipped also.

Comment: Your own solution gives the same answers! I can't think of any other possible birthday for someone claiming to be 1 year old on the 29th of February. I've added clauses to determine which year/month to count when subtracting, which addresses the ends of months. Saying the whole approach doesn't work is a bit dismissive. I've clearly stated it's a naive approach.

Comment: @BenjaminPenney—the issue is doing the subtractions one at a time, i.e. year, then month, then day. E.g. someone born on 29 Jan 2019 is 1 year, 1 month old on 29 Feb 2020. If you subtract the year first, then you get 1 March (because there's no 29 Feb 2019). Then subtract the month you get 1 February. If you do both together, then you get 29 January. Admittedly they are not common occurrences, so they are very difficult to find. :-)

Comment: PS. If you post your code as a runnable snippet it's easier to test here. :-)

Comment: I can't let this subtracting one-at-a-time nonsense stand. Arithmetic and unit conversions aren't magic. Subtracting days, using the Date constructor or even Moment.js are all valid solutions. I won't downvote @RobG 's solution but at the same time, there's nothing wrong with teaching people how mechanisms like this work. There is something wrong, however, with suggesting that this solution has problems it doesn't, suggesting that it subtracts one at a time, claiming a month is supposed to be clamped and then saying such a result would be 'undefined' in your own answer...